# Harris corner using Emgu CV

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

Im trying to apply Harris corners using Emgu CV Wrapper, and I'm learning from a book titled "Open CV 2, Computer Vision Application Cook Book" , the book examples are based on C++, below is their example on Harris after replacing cv::Mat with it's equivalent on Emgu MCvMat, however that didn't compile so I used the "data" field on the MCvMat object, it did compile but it hangs, no error no exception but it just hang.

```
 MCvMat cornerStrength = new MCvMat(); ;
 CvInvoke.cvCornerHarris(Global.GrayImage.Ptr, cornerStrength.data, 3, 3, 0.1);
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, I've just downloaded a PDF of the book, installed Emgu CV, and followed the same process as you did. Except I succeeded ;-)

I think all you missed was that you need to create an empty 32-bit float image to receive the corner strengths before you call `cvCornerHarris`. Then you pass the `Image` objects to it.

Here are the main parts of my code, which I developed in a Windows Forms application in C# using Visual Studio 2012. First, a few member variables I used to hold the image objects:

```
// original source image as grayscale
private Image<Gray, Byte> m_SourceImage = null;

// raw corner strength image (must be 32-bit float)
private Image<Gray, float> m_CornerImage = null;

// inverted thresholded corner strengths (for display)
private Image<Gray, Byte> m_ThresholdImage = null;
```

Now, a button click handler to prompt for an image to load from file and display it:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // prompt for source image
    OpenFileDialog Openfile = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (Openfile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // create and show source image as grayscale
        m_SourceImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(Openfile.FileName);
        pictureBox1.Image = m_SourceImage.ToBitmap();
    }
}
```

Finally, the button click handler for performing the corner detection:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // create corner strength image and do Harris
    m_CornerImage = new Image<Gray, float>(m_SourceImage.Size);
    CvInvoke.cvCornerHarris(m_SourceImage, m_CornerImage, 3, 3, 0.01);

    // create and show inverted threshold image
    m_ThresholdImage = new Image<Gray, Byte>(m_SourceImage.Size);
    CvInvoke.cvThreshold(m_CornerImage, m_ThresholdImage, 0.0001, 
        255.0, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.THRESH.CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    pictureBox1.Image = m_ThresholdImage.ToBitmap();
}
```

In the above code, you can see I have followed the example from the book and applied a threshold to the corner image and inverted the result for easier display. You could just show `m_CornerImage` instead.

Here are some screenshots of the result - the loaded image (as grayscale) on the left, and the inverted threshold image showing the corner strengths on the right:

[image: harris]

Please comment or edit your question if you need any further information or help and I'll do my best.

Comment: Thank you , I was using Byte instead of float, the bounty will be available to be rewarded in 20 hours , I will make sure to do it

Comment: @Musaab - my pleasure - many thanks for the bounty, I'll look forward to it :-)

Comment: cant find cvCornerHarris in LastVersion Of Emgucv

Comment: @ehsanwwe Well, it's in the documentation - [http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/a5c2c941-4420-0b46-eac4-1b3fa9dbaf10.htm](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/a5c2c941-4420-0b46-eac4-1b3fa9dbaf10.htm).